# Qt Creator class view, track open file / selected item from the source code editor

Tags: qt, class, view, ide, qt-creator

I'm relatively newbie to qt creator doing embedded cpp work. I was wondering if there is a way for the class view side bar to show the active class I'm working on in the editor window? I also tried to do a search using locator "c MyClass" to show MyClass, the locator manages to find MyClass, however when I click it, it opens in editor window, it is tracked in the Project sidebar but it is not tracked in the Class View SideBar. Am I missing any settings?

Qt Creator 3.4.1
Based on Qt 5.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there is a way in Qt Creator for the class view side bar to show the active class
>   I'm working on in the editor window?

Yes, choose `Outline` in the hierarchy menu on the left. Mind that you can use `Split` button (find it by hovering over the second from the right top button there) for having more than one type of project hierarchy there.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @AlexanderVX. Exactly what I was looking for. Hehe, I was so fixated on class view, I didn't try outline. =)

Comment: Don't forget to accept and up so I look better while arguing on other serious issues. :)

Comment: Hehe, sure, I upped it but it won't show because I have not enough comments from my profile. Don't worry, if you're in the right, no one shud be able to put you down. =)